# How to handle custom GraphQL error such that it does not display the exception stack trace in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, error-handling, graphql

I have created a simple GraphQL endpoint using Spring Boot and I am using DefaultGraphQLErrorHandler() to handle GraphQL errors.

However, when I throw a custom Exception from my application, the error response which GraphQL produces contains Exception stack trace which is giving away too much information. I want to prevent this.

```
{
"data": {
    "CommercialAsset": null
},
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "Exception while fetching data (/CommercialAsset) : Asset not fround in Data source",
        "path": [
            "CommercialAsset"
        ],
        "exception": {
            "cause": null,
            "stackTrace": [
                {
                    "classLoaderName": null,
                    "moduleName": null,
                    "moduleVersion": null,
                    "methodName": "getAssetById",
                    "fileName": "CommercialAssetDremioRepositoryImpl.java",
                    "lineNumber": 49,
                    "className": "com.dell.dremioclient.repository.impl.CommercialAssetDremioRepositoryImpl",
                    "nativeMethod": false
                },
                ...
                {
                    "classLoaderName": null,
                    "moduleName": "java.base",
                    "moduleVersion": "11.0.14",
                    "methodName": "run",
                    "fileName": "Thread.java",
                    "lineNumber": 834,
                    "className": "java.lang.Thread",
                    "nativeMethod": false
                }
            ],
            "message": "Asset not fround in Data source",
            "locations": null,
            "errorType": null,
            "path": null,
            "extensions": null,
            "suppressed": [],
            "localizedMessage": "Asset not fround in Data source"
        },
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 2,
                "column": 5,
                "sourceName": null
            }
        ],
        "extensions": null,
        "errorType": "DataFetchingException"
    }
]
```

}

GraphQL dependency versions that I am using :

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is there any way I can do it using Custom error handler? Something like this -

```
public class CustomGraphqlErrorHandler implements GraphQLErrorHandler {

@Override
public List<GraphQLError> processErrors(List<GraphQLError> errors) {
    
    List<GraphQLError> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    errors.stream()
            .forEach( e -> {
                if(this.isServerError(e)) {
                    GraphqlDremioClientException gexp = new GraphqlDremioClientException(e.getMessage());
                    gexp.setStackTrace(null); /* This causes failure Bad POST request: parsing failed
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: null
                                                 at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.setStackTrace(Throwable.java:865) */
                    errorList.add(gexp);
                } else {
                    errorList.add(e);
                }
            });
    
    return errorList;
}

private boolean isServerError(GraphQLError error) {
    return (error instanceof ExceptionWhileDataFetching || error instanceof Throwable);
}

@Override
public boolean errorsPresent(List<GraphQLError> errors) {
    return !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(errors);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to prevent GraphQL to show stack trace in the error response. One simple solution to it was to add a custom GraphQL error handler to handle the exceptions thrown from my services. I then, created a custom Exception class which could enable or disable stack trace during construction.

Custom Exception class:

```
public class GraphqlDremioClientException extends RuntimeException implements GraphQLError {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private final String message;
    
    private boolean writeStacktrace = false;

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    /* other constructors */
        
    public GraphqlDremioClientException(String message, boolean writeStacktrace) {
        super(message, null, false, writeStacktrace);
        this.writeStacktrace = writeStacktrace;
        this.message = message;
    }
    
    public GraphqlDremioClientException(String message, Exception ex) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public List<SourceLocation> getLocations() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ErrorType getErrorType() {
        return null;
    }       
}
```

Custome GraphQL error handler:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class CustomGraphqlErrorHandler implements GraphQLErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public List<GraphQLError> processErrors(List<GraphQLError> list) {
        return list.stream().map(this::getNested).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    private GraphQLError getNested(GraphQLError error) {
        log.error(error.getMessage(), error);
        
        if (error instanceof ExceptionWhileDataFetching) {
            ExceptionWhileDataFetching exceptionError = (ExceptionWhileDataFetching) error;
            if (exceptionError.getException() instanceof GraphQLError) {
                return new GraphqlDremioClientException(exceptionError.getMessage(), false);
            }
        }
        return error;
    }
}
```

The error response now:

```
{
    "data": {
        "CommercialAsset": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "cause": null,
            "stackTrace": [],
            "message": "Exception while fetching data (/CommercialAsset) : Asset not fround in Data source",
            "writeStacktrace": false,
            "locations": null,
            "errorType": null,
            "path": null,
            "extensions": null,
            "suppressed": [],
            "localizedMessage": "Exception while fetching data (/CommercialAsset) : Asset not fround in Data source"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve with spring-boot-starter-graphql from spring project? Not able to find GraphQLErrorHandler class ? Can you please suggest how it can be configured?

Comment: @rubalvjaiswal see this answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/74947705/7436256

Answer (score 4):

For those using `spring-boot-starter-graphql` from spring project:

There are two cases to consider

A. Exceptions that happen when `DataFetchers` have been registered during request execution. Such exceptions are passed to `DataFetcherExceptionResolverAdapter` to handle. You can implement custom error handlers like below;

```java
import graphql.GraphQLError;
import graphql.GraphqlErrorBuilder;
import graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.DataFetcherExceptionResolverAdapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@Component
public class CustomErrorResolver extends DataFetcherExceptionResolverAdapter {


    @Override
    protected GraphQLError resolveToSingleError(Throwable ex, DataFetchingEnvironment env) {
        Throwable t = NestedExceptionUtils.getMostSpecificCause(ex);

        if (t instanceof YourCustomException customException) {
            return GraphqlErrorBuilder.newError(env)
                    .errorType(ErrorTypes.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .message(customException.getMessage() + "your custom message")
                    .build();
        }

        if( t instanceof ConstraintViolationException constraintViolationException){
            return validationError(constraintViolationException, env);
        }

      // other exceptions not yet caught
        return GraphqlErrorBuilder.newError(env)
                .message("Error occurred: Ensure request is valid ")
                .errorType(ErrorTypes.BAD_REQUEST)
                .build();
    }

    private GraphQLError validationError(ConstraintViolationException exception, DataFetchingEnvironment env){
        String invalidFields = exception.getConstraintViolations().stream()
                .map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

        return GraphqlErrorBuilder.newError(env)
                .errorType(ErrorTypes.BAD_REQUEST)
                .message(invalidFields)
                .build();
    }
}
```

B. The second case is exceptions thrown before GraphQL registers any `DataFetcher`. In this case, if you want to control the error message displayed, then create an Interceptor.

```java
import graphql.GraphQLError;
import graphql.GraphqlErrorBuilder;
import org.springframework.graphql.server.WebGraphQlInterceptor;
import org.springframework.graphql.server.WebGraphQlRequest;
import org.springframework.graphql.server.WebGraphQlResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
class RequestErrorInterceptor implements WebGraphQlInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Mono<WebGraphQlResponse> intercept(WebGraphQlRequest request, Chain chain) {

        return chain.next(request).map(response -> {
            if (response.isValid()) {
                return response;
            }

            List<GraphQLError> errors = response.getErrors().stream()
                    .map(error -> GraphqlErrorBuilder.newError()
                            .message("Request error. Ensure request is valid and try again.")
                            .errorType(ErrorTypes.BAD_REQUEST)
                            .build())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return response.transform(builder -> builder.errors(errors).build());
        });
    }
}
```

Custom ErrorClassification

```java
import graphql.ErrorClassification;

public enum ErrorTypes implements ErrorClassification {
    BAD_REQUEST,
    UNAUTHORIZED,
    FORBIDDEN,
    NOT_FOUND ,
    INTERNAL_ERROR
}
```